# Deriving the BISG Bayesian probability formula

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

The paper

> Bureau, C. F. P. (2014). Using publicly available information to proxy for unidentified race and ethnicity: A methodology and assessment. Washington, DC: CFPB, Summer. [1]

provides a methodology to impute race from surname and geography, but I am struggling to understand how the formula for this is derived. Technical Appendix A states

> Apply Bayes’ Theorem to calculate the likelihood that an individual with surname s living in geographic area g belongs to race or ethnicity r. This is described by
> $$
> \text{Pr}(r|g,s) = \frac{p(r|s) q(g|r)}{\sum_{r \in R} p * q}
> $$

but I am struggling to derive this with my limited knowledge of Bayes theorem.

Can someone please provide a step-by-step derivation of this formula?

[1] https://files.consumerfinance.gov/f/201409_cfpb_report_proxy-methodology.pdf

Thank you!

Comment: The equation seems wrong to me. You need Pr(s|r) and Pr(g|r) in the numerator on the RHS. Some assumptions I think they have made are: independence of g,s given r and prior probabilities of all races being the same. But you need to confirm this with the authors of the report.

Comment: Thanks @RahulMadhavan . Yes the report assumes independence of g|r and s: 

>  To maintain the statistical validity of the Bayesian updating process, one assumption is required: the probability of residing in a given geography, given one’s race, is independent of one’s surname. For example, the accuracy of the proxy would be impacted if Blacks with the last name Jones preferred to live in a certain neighborhood more than both Blacks in general and all people with the last name Jones.

Comment: I have found the paper Elliott et al. 2009 which this is based on [1] but I am still struggling to reproduce.

The paper states "We require an assumption that the probability of residing in a given Block Group, given a person’s race, does not vary by surname." which I interpret as $\text{Pr}(g|r,s) = \text{Pr}(g|r)$ and the paper equates $\text{Pr}(r,s,g) = \text{Pr}(r|s) \text{Pr}(g|r)$ but I am still unable to make this work. So far I have $\text{Pr}(r,s,g) = \text{Pr}(g,r|s)$

[1] https://www.thecre.com/insurance/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/CFPB-Paper.pdf

Comment: I've amended the answer to reflect the assumption you have provided. Pls check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

**Second Document:**
We can calculate the probability of a race given surname and geography using Bayes theorem as follows:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P[R|G,S] &= \frac{\mathbb P[R,G,S]}{\mathbb P[G,S]}\\
\mathbb P[R|G,S] &= \frac{\mathbb P[R,G,S]}{\sum\limits_{R_i} \mathbb P[R_i,G,S]}\\
\end{align*}

**First Document (linked in question)**
Assume: (1) $\mathbb P [G|R,S] = \mathbb P [G|R]$

\begin{align*}
\mathbb P[R|G,S] &= \frac{\mathbb P[R,G|S]}{\mathbb P[G|S]}\\
\mathbb P[R|G,S] &= \frac{\mathbb P[R,G|S]}{\sum\limits_{R_i} \mathbb P[R_i,G|S]}\\
&= \frac{\mathbb P[G|R,S]\times \mathbb P[R|S]}{\sum\limits_{R_i} \mathbb P[G|R_i,S]\times \mathbb P[R_i|S]}\\
\end{align*}
Now we use the assumption that $\mathbb P [G|R,S] = \mathbb P [G|R]$, whence:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P[R|G,S] 
&= \frac{\mathbb P[G|R]\times \mathbb P[R|S]}{\sum\limits_{R_i} \mathbb P[G|R_i]\times \mathbb P[R_i|S]}\\
\end{align*}

This is the equation linked in the paper.

---

PS: It's hard to reverse engineer the assumptions under which some statement holds